# RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory - DCGAN with image_size = 256

Tags: python, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network, dcgan

I am trying to implement a DCGAN with `image_size = 256` (using PyTorch). I already implemented the generator and discriminator codes, in the following:

```
class Generator(nn.Module):
def init(self, ngpu):
super(Generator, self).init()
self.ngpu = ngpu
self.main = nn.Sequential(
# input is Z, going into a convolution
nn.ConvTranspose2d( nz, ngf * 32, 4, 1, 0, bias=False),
nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 32),
nn.ReLU(True),
# state size. (ngf32) x 4 x 4
nn.ConvTranspose2d( ngf * 32, ngf * 16, 4, 2, 0, bias=False),
nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 16),
nn.ReLU(True),
# state size. (ngf16) x 8 x 8
nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 16, ngf * 8, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 8),
nn.ReLU(True),
# state size. (ngf8) x 16 x 16
nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 8, ngf * 4, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 4),
nn.ReLU(True),
# state size. (ngf4) x 32 x 32
nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 4, ngf * 2, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 2),
nn.ReLU(True),
# state size. (ngf*2) x 64 x 64
nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 2, ngf, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf),
nn.ReLU(True),
# state size. (ngf) x 128 x 128
nn.ConvTranspose2d( ngf, nc, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
nn.Tanh()
# state size. (nc) x 256 x 256
)

class Discriminator(nn.Module):
def init(self, ngpu):
super(Discriminator, self).init()
self.ngpu = ngpu
self.main = nn.Sequential(
# input is (nc) x 256 x 256
nn.Conv2d(nc, ndf, 4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
# state size. (ndf) x 128 x 128
nn.Conv2d(ndf, ndf * 2, 4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 2),
nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
# state size. (ndf2) x 64 x 64
nn.Conv2d(ndf * 2, ndf * 4, 4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 4),
nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
# state size. (ndf4) x 32 x 32
nn.Conv2d(ndf * 4, ndf * 8, 4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 8),
nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
# state size. (ndf8) x 16 x 16
nn.Conv2d(ndf * 8, ndf * 16, 4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 16),
nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
# state size. (ndf6) x 8 x 8
nn.Conv2d(ndf * 16, ndf * 32, 4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 32),
nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
# state size. (ndf*32) x 4 x 4
nn.Conv2d(ndf * 32, 1, 4, stride=1, padding=0, bias=False),
nn.Sigmoid()
# state size. 1
)
```

After reading something at the GAN forums, I found that the `batch_size` must be low, considering I am using a *GTX 1050 Ti* with *4GB* of memory (actually, my `batch_size` variable is set to `5`).

I am finding the error:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Update 2: Resizing code

```
# Create the dataset
dataset = dset.ImageFolder(root=dataroot,
                       transform=transforms.Compose([
                           transforms.Resize(image_size),
                           transforms.CenterCrop(image_size),
                           transforms.ToTensor(),
                           transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)),
                       ]))
# Create the dataloader
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                     shuffle=True, num_workers=workers)
```

Comment: 4GB is not much. try even lower batch size

Comment: Are your images by default 256x256 or are you resizing them prior to feeding it to your gan network? you can try running nvidia-smi -l and then run your script. the nvidia-smi command gives you the amount of gpu memory being consumed by each process accessing the gpu. you can then try out setting different batch sizes and check the batch size your gpu can handle. Alternatively, you can resize your image further down before feeding it to your network. This way you can increase your batch processing capacity. But be careful about the implications of resizing, if any.

Comment: @Shai I've tried even batch_size = 1, and the same problem occurred. But I believe the network architecture for both generator and discriminator are fine, aren't them?

Comment: @ShubhamJaiswal My image are, by default, sized of 1024 x 1024, but I am trying to provide artificial images with size of 256 x 256.

Comment: @Luis Souza how are you reszing them, can you share your code?

Comment: can you provide the values for `nc`, `ndf`, `ngf`?

Comment: @ShubhamJaiswal The code for the dataset resizing in Update 2.

Comment: @iacolippo 
nz = 100;
nc = 3;
ngf = 128; 
ndf = 32